# Openstack heat environment parameter file default value invalid error

Tags: openstack, openstack-heat

I'm trying to create a stack with a template file and an environment parameter file. Below are my details.

**In Template File:**

```
v6_ip:
  type: string
  description: ipv6 address
  constraints:
    - length: { min: 1, max: 46 }
  default: 0

v6_prefix_len:
  type: number
  description: ipv6 prefix length
  constraints:
    - range: { min: 0, max: 128 }
  default: 0

v6_gateway:
  type: string
  description: ipv6 default gateway
  constraints:
    - length: { min: 1, max: 46 }
  default: 0

server:
    type: OS::Nova::Server
    properties:
      name: { get_param : my_name }
      metadata:
      config_drive: True
      user_data:
        params:      
          $IPV4: { get_param: v4_ip }
          $V4_NETMASK: { get_param: v4_netmask }
          $V4_GW: { get_param: v4_gateway }
          $IPV6: { get_param: v6_ip }
          $V6_PREFIX: { get_param: v6_prefix_len }
          $V6_GW: { get_param: v6_gateway }
```

**The environment file:**

```
v4_ip: 192.168.11.179
v4_netmask: 255.255.240.0
v4_gateway: 192.168.0.254
v6_ip: fd5d:d50a:8c17:2110::2019
v6_prefix_len: 64
v6_gateway: fd5d:d50a:8c17:2110::ff
```

When I try to create the stack, I'm getting the below error:

> ERROR: Parameter 'v6_gateway' is invalid: Invalid default 0 (object of
>   type 'int' has no len())

I've defined `v6_gateway` as string and default value is 0. The same thing for `v4_gateway` it's accepting. Why it's throwing an error for `v6_gateway`? Also how to resolve it?

PS: I'm using openstack newton version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your default gateway is an number, and not a string. If you really need the default `0` to be valid as-is, you can wrap it with apostrophes.

```
v6_gateway:
  type: string
  description: ipv6 default gateway
  constraints:
    - length: { min: 1, max: 46 }
  default: '0'
```

Comment: TO be true, I wanted to try the same. But than got confused, for all other details of IPv4 and IPv6 I'm using the same. And it was throwing error here only. Okay. Lemme try and get back to u.